# SQLAlchemy doubles percent sign in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, mariadb

Get troubles with execution some queries with % symbol.

Here is query for example, in Jupyter Notebook, MariaDB, SQL Alchemy as sa:

```
query = f'''

SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT id_user),
       DATE_FORMAT(time, '%m-%Y') as my
FROM invest_activity
WHERE id_user = 1791237
GROUP BY my
    
'''

id_user_sample = pd.read_sql(sa.text(query), con = connection_)
```

So, if I use this, it will produce error such as:

> ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; ...
> SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT id_user),
> DATE_FORMAT(time, '%%m-%%Y') as my ...

Tried to use different version of SQL Alchemy 1.4 and 2.0, also tried to use r-srting, sa.text, different types of quotes, escaping symbols, etc, but nothing works. See some topics here also, but examples didn't work either.

Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my simplified solution, kinda workaround, I guess.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

connection_ = sa.create_engine(['...some_credentials...'],
                                 dialect = postgresql.dialect(paramstyle = 'named')).connect()

df = pd.read_sql(sa.text(query), con = connection_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the percent signs. They need to be doubled-up when passed to the DBAPI layer. Otherwise they would be misinterpreted as the start of a parameter placeholder.

Your problem is the space in `COUNT (DISTINCT id_user)`, which is interpreted as `COUNT` (keyword) instead of `COUNT()` (function). So use `COUNT(DISTINCT id_user)`.

Comment: Thanks, but nope, doesn't work, get the same result with error.

Comment: I dunno, [this code](https://gist.github.com/ba0867776fac6f88c262b34cf88f4fd4) doesn't give me that error.

Comment: You are probably right too. I tried it on other computers, sometimes the code really works, but not everywhere, while there is no obvious understanding of what the difference is. Thx.